# Pandas Change from 1 Minute to 15 Minutes average value

Tags: pandas, average

I got a Dataframe with 4 columns in 1 Minute average value, but i need it in 15 Minutes average value. Do you know a function or something else to fix the problem?

I founnd already the function split(df, "minutes", k=15) but i don´t know how it works.

Comment: Are you after [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)?

Comment: Yes, that is the function :)....and how can i get the average over the downsample time?

Comment: For upsampling it introduces `NaN` but you can pass 'mean' so `df.resample('15min', how='mean')` should work

Comment: Sorry the default is `mean` for downsampling so it should just work

Comment: Jahresgang.resample('15min', how='mean'), this is what i have written. And now i get this error. Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex. Its should be the wrong dtypes or?

Comment: it means that `resample` only works when the index is a `datetime` like index, so you'd need to set the index first#

Comment: And how can i do this when i get this dtypes: Zeitstempel                   datetime64[ns]
Wirkleistung_effektiv_W               object
Scheinleistung_effektiv_VA            object
Spannung_effektiv_V                   object
dtype: object

Comment: `df.set_index('Zeitstempel').resample('15min')`

Comment: it works good, but now is my Datetime in the firs column away. is that normal?

Comment: Yes, you can then call `reset_index()` to restore it back as a column, if all this works then I'll post an answer but you should in the future post raw input data, code to reproduce your df and what the desired df looks like